# Unresolved reference for Holdr in Kotlin

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, kotlin

I am trying to use a library called Holdr (https://github.com/evant/holdr) to generate classes based on my layout files to easily reference views in those layouts in my activities.

I can verify that the classes are generated fine at build time

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

Class for layout activity_main.xml generates Holdr_ActivityMain.java in

```
app/build/generated/source/holdr/
```

Kotlin gives me two errors during the task

```
:app:compileDebugKotlin
```

Errors

```
e: (8, 44): Unresolved reference: holdr
e: (12, 24): Unresolved reference: Holdr_ActivityMain
```

Here is my class

```
import com.myapp.holdr.Holdr_ActivityMain

public class MainActivity : Activity() {

    private var holdr: Holdr_ActivityMain? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

}
```

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.holdr'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/java'
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}

buildscript {

    ext.kotlin_version = '0.10.770'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'me.tatarka.holdr:gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Related issue in Kotlin's bugtracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17989

Answer (score 1):

What Kotlin Gradle plugin version do you use?

For now, you could specify the Holdr sources path explicitly as a workaround:

```
sourceSets {
    ...
    debug.java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/holdr/debug'
    release.java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/holdr/release'
}
```

Comment: I'm using classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" with ext.kotlin_version = '0.10.770', though the Kotlin Android Studio plugin version I have installed is 0.10.195.25. Thanks for the workaround.

Comment: The writer of holdr commented on my question in G+ with: "I have not tried getting it to work with kotlin, but in theory it should. I'm using a method provided by the android plugin "registerJavaGeneratingTask" in order to add the generated sources to the classpath for compilation. It's possible that the kotlin plugin is mucking with things in such a way that the directory is no longer being picked up. It's a bit understandable since this option is hardly documented (The only reference I can find is in the 0.7.0 release notes https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/ersS6fMLxw1)."

Comment: Oh, sorry, I actually wanted to ask what Android Gradle plugin do you use. But if the workaround works, maybe there's no problem with that.
Anyway, I'll investigate this, it looks like a bug in Kotlin Gradle plugin.

Comment: I'm using 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'

Comment: Did you find a real fix on this bug? I wrote a plugin to generate code using the registerJavaGeneratingTask method, I can write my Kotlin code, the classes are detected, but on build time, kotlin fails

Comment: @badoualy That's the exact problem I'm seeing right now with my Kotlin Android app build scripts. *registerJavaGeneratingTask* doesn't affect sources for Kotlin classes, and  it fails on build time. Did you find any solution for this? Hello from 2019 btw :)